# Opening a 2010 excel file corrupted by excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, dll

I created a VBA in Excel 2010 which generates an email. My colleague opened the file in Excel 2016 then saved it. Then I opened the file in version 2010 I get an error message. 'Error in loading DLL' When I check the tools, references, I see 'Missing: Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library'. I lost my all macros in the file. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you send it by e-mail and therefore have it as an attachment in its old form?

Answer (score 0):

In VBA Editor >>>  Tools  >>> References:

Deselect the missing *Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library* and select the reference version installed on your machine.

But to solve this problem for good, you should remove the reference to Outlook, declare the object as `Object` and use late binding:

```
Dim app As Object
Set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Comment: But doesn’t explain the loss of macros does it?

Comment: Saved as `.xlsx` perhaps?

Comment: No 1 rule: Always keep a backup.

Comment: Thanks! When I untick the missing tool, it says 'Can't perform requested operation'. I can't save the file. Luckily I have backup. I think that file is totally corrupted, I try again with object declaration.

Comment: Try again with late binding. Also, get into the habit of exporting your code so you have it in a safe place. Lots of options around this detailed on internet and examples on SO. Be aware also that data models when moving between versions in an upward fashion e.g. 2010 to 2016 will irreversibly be corrupted.